# Magento2 not able to load the wishlist product Id

Tags: magento2, wishlist

Magento2 not able to load wishlist products Id's. I am using following method to load the Id's. Please advice

```
$customer_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); 

$wishlist_collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist')->loadByCustomerId($customer_id)->getItemCollection();

print_r($wishlist_collection->getData());die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for get ID or Name of product

```
$customer_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); 

$wishlist_collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist')->loadByCustomerId($customer_id)->getItemCollection();

//print_r($wishlist_collection->getData());die();
   
 if(count($wishlist_collection)) {
        foreach ($wishlist_collection as $_item) {
            echo $_item->getProduct()->getName(); echo "<br>";
            echo $_item->getProduct()->getId(); echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```